# reading Word file from POST request in grails

Tags: http, rest, grails, post, groovy

I'm trying to write a Groovy script that will post a Word (docx) file to a REST handler on my grails application.

The request is constructed like so:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient

class RestFileUploader {
    def sendFile(file, filename) {

        def url = 'http://url.of.my.app';


        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);


        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
        reqEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody((File)file, "application/msword"));

        def normalizedFilename = filename.replace(" ", "")
        reqEntity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody(normalizedFilename));

        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        httppost.setHeader('X-File-Size', (String)file.size())
        httppost.setHeader('X-File-Name', filename)
        httppost.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=utf-8')

        println "about to post..."

        HttpResponse restResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = restResponse.getEntity();
        def responseXml = resEntity.content.text;

        println "posted..."
        println restResponse
        println resEntity

        println responseXml.toString()

        return responseXml.toString()

    }
}
```

On the receiving controller, I read in the needed headers from the request, and then try to access the file like so:

```
def inStream = request.getInputStream()
```

I end up writing out a corrupted Word file, and from examining the file size and the contents, it looks like my controller is writing out the entire request, rather than just the file.

I've also tried this approach:

```
def filePart = request.getPart('file')
def inStream = filePart.getInputStream()
```

In this case I end up with an empty input stream and nothing gets written out.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the file is an attachment, then it becomes part of the MultipartHttpRequest. You would need `request.getFile('fileName')` where `fileName` is the name used to POST the file.

Comment: @dmahapatro I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "attachment".  Are you saying that based on this line: `reqEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody((File)file, "application/msword")' I would use `request.getFile('file')?  When I've tried that I get the following exception: `No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [file]`

Comment: I neglected to mention that I'm using SpringSecurity in my grails application, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make two changes:

1. Remove the line: `httppost.setHeader('Content-Type'...`.  File upload HTTP POST requests must have content type `multipart/form-data`  (set automatically by HttpClient when you construct a multipart HttpPost)
2. Change the line: `reqEntity.addPart("file", ...` to: `reqEntity.addPart("file", new
   FileBody(file))`. Or use one of the other non-deprecated `FileBody` constructors to specify a valid content type and charset ([API link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html))  This assumes that your `file` method parameter is of type `java.io.File` -- this isn't clear to me from your snippet.

Then, as dmahapatro suggests, you should be able to read the file with: `request.getFile('file')`

Comment: Still no luck.  The request I'm getting is a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWra‌​pper` which does not have a `getFile` method.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail about the Grails controller action that's accepting the POST?  Specifically, how are you applying Spring Security to the action (if at all)?

Comment: The action is contained in a secured controller, but I'm overriding the controller-level security settings with a `@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'])` annotation on my new action.  Before, my POST request was getting a redirect to the login page of my application.